# Connect in stream Socket (port 443) using React-Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets

I am trying to connect to a Betfair server via Socket. using the native reaction.

In the official documentation, there is an example of how to connect via node: https://github.com/betfair/stream-api-sample-code/blob/master/node.js/app.js.

In this example above it is used: "const tls = require ('tls');", but from what I saw this module only exists in Node, and not in ReactNative.

I tried to use socket.io-client, but without success. after socket.connect (), nothing happens.

Can someone help me?